# Obtain the number of features in a Shapefile using NodeJS

Tags: shapefile, features, command-line, count, node-js

I'm using the `shapefile` NPM library which works well, but it doesn't provide a count of the number of features in a Shapefile. Is there some other library which can access this information (other than shelling out to `ogrinfo`), or some other technique?

Comment: Shapefile_feature_count = (dBase_file_size - dBase_header_size) / dBase_record_size
also Shapefile_feature_count = littleEndianInt(bytes 4-7 of .dbf file header)

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful info - not sure if that library exposes such low level details yet.

Comment: Ok, I've opened a pull request there now.